# Remove duplicate data in result from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server and need help with one of my SQL query.

I have 2 tables (`Rating` and `LikeDislike`).

I am trying to get data from both of these tables using a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
   R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, R.Extra, LD.UserName, LD.Clikes
FROM 
   Rating As R
LEFT JOIN 
   LikeDislike AS LD ON LD.TopicID = R.ID
ORDER BY 
   R.ID DESC
```

The above `SELECT` statement displays results fine but also includes duplicates. I want to remove duplicates when the data is displayed, I tried using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, but with no luck, maybe because I am not using it correctly.

**Update:** To be more clear and less confusing let me tell you what exactly each table does and what I am trying to achieve.

The `Rating` table has following columns (`ID, Topic, CountLikes, CountDisLikes, Extra, CreatedByUser`). It stores topic information and number of likes and dislikes for each topics and the `UserID` of the user who created that topic.

The `LikeDisLike` table has following columns (`ID, TopicID, UserName, Clikes`). `TopicID` is a FK to the `ID` column in `Rating` table.

Now what I am trying to do is get information from both of this table without duplicate rows. I need to get data all the columns from `Rating` table + `UserName` and `Clikes` columns from `LikeDislike` table without any duplicate rows

Update 2:
Below are the results with duplicates with this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT  
   DISTINCT ld.TopicID, R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, 
   LD.UserName, LD.Clikes 
FROM 
   Rating AS R 
LEFT JOIN 
   LikeDislike AS LD ON  LD.TopicID = R.ID
```

Resulting output:

```
TopicID ID  Topic            CountLikes   CountDislikes UserName    Clikes
NULL    79  Testing at home    1           0             NULL       NULL
NULL    80  Testing at home2   1           0             NULL       NULL 
NULL    82  testing dislikes   0           1             NULL       NULL
1       1   Do You Like This   211         58            3          FALSE
2       2   Or This            17          25            3          TRUE
76      76  Testing part 3     7           5             2          FALSE
76      76  Testing part 3     7           5             3          FALSE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             2          TRUE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             3          TRUE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             5          TRUE
```

Comment: If your above query is returning duplicates (and you have tried select distinct), it's likely one of your columns is different, presumably your ID column in your Rating table.  What is your current output?

Comment: Can you give examples of the results you are getting and the input data?

Comment: one of your columns maybe have a different value in duplicated row

Comment: Also it may be one of your columns/tables is in different encoding

Comment: If you want to get all matching rows from `LikeDislike` reduced down to a single row as part of this join, you need to tell *us* (and eventually, SQL Server), *how* to reduce these rows. E.g. taking the last 3 rows from your output. There are different `UserName` (and, potentially, `CLikes`) values - how should we choose what to show here? (Don't say "the first row", or similar, unless you have some definition, based on the available columns, of what it means for a row to be first)

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax should remove complete duplicates:

```
SELECT distinct R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, R.Extra,
       LD.UserName, LD.Clikes
FROM Rating As R
LEFT JOIN LikeDislike AS LD on LD.TopicID = R.ID
ORDER BY R.ID desc
```

Is this what you tried?

Comment: What is the problem?  I suspect the SQL is working but you have different expectations of what it should be doing.

Comment: When I run the above select statement with the Distinct clause, it still displays all the duplicates, instead of removing them. However after some google search I came up to this SELECT statement which removes the duplicates "SELECT R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, R.Extra, TopicID FROM Rating AS R Left Join ( SELECT TopicID From LikeDisLike Group by TopicID) AS LD on R.ID = LD.TopicID ORDER By R.ID Desc"

Comment: The above code works, it also removes duplicate rows but how do I display more columns from the LikeDislike table

Comment: @Aaf - You removed the LD.UserName and LD.Clicks columns -- I suspect that's why it worked. What is your desired outcome?  Obviously LD.UserName or LD.Clikes has non-distinct rows.  Good luck.

Comment: To be more clear and less confusing let me tell you what exactly each table does and what I am trying to acheive.
The Rating table has following Columns (ID, Topic, CountLikes, CountDisLikes, Extra, CreatedByUser). It stores Topic information and number of likes and dislikes for each topics and the UserID of the user who created that topic.
The LikeDisLike table has following columns (ID, TopicID, UserName, Clikes). TopicID is a FK to the ID column in Rating table.
Now what I am trying to do is Get information from both of this table without duplicate rows.

Comment: So all the Columns from Rating Table + UserName and Clikes columns from LikeDislike table

Comment: @Aaf . . . You should edit your original question with this information.

Comment: @Aaf: using `DISTINCT` **will** remove actual duplicates - I'm suspecting your definition of "duplicate" doesn't match what SQL considers a duplicate (a row with all columns identical to the values of another row)

Comment: @marc, Thanks for the explanation of duplicate, you are right. I guess the reason it is not removing duplicates is because all the rows are not identical, then what should I do in such scenario ?

Comment: @Aaf . . . As I and other have suggested, revise the question (or at this point ask a new one) where you show sample data and sample results.  That is the easiest way to convey what you need.

Comment: Created a new question with more details, please take a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402109/microsoft-sql-remove-duplicate-data-from-query-results

Comment: Mods, please close or delete this question. I have created a new one

Answer (score 0):

i  think this   way will provide you proper output

```
select ID, Topic,CountLikes,CountDisLikes,Extra,
   UserName, Clikes from (
    SELECT distinct R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, R.Extra,
   LD.UserName, LD.Clikes
            , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by R.ID order by R.ID desc) as rid
   FROM Rating As R
    LEFT JOIN LikeDislike AS LD on LD.TopicID = R.ID
    ORDER BY R.ID desc) t where rid=1 order by ID desc
```

are else  please check   the likedislike  tbl  where  u are inserting   2 topic for same id of rating tbl and also check  UserName, Clikes also whether they are similar in likedislike  tbl

Comment: I am getting error 'There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 5,Token line offset = 28,Token in error = over ]' with the above query command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SELECT R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, R.Extra, 
LD.UserName, LD.Clikes  FROM Rating AS R 
        Left Join ( SELECT TopicID, UserName, min(Clikes) as Clikes 
    From LikeDisLike Group by TopicID,UserName) AS LD 
on R.ID = LD.TopicID ORDER By R.ID Desc
```

By the way, I think you need UNIQUE(TopicID,UserName) constraint to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I am getting error 'The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = min ]'

Comment: Maybe mistake in column name.