# Microsoft SQL - Remove duplicate data from query results

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server and need help with one of my SQL query.

I have 2 tables (`Rating` and `LikeDislike`).

I am trying to get data from both of these tables using a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT distinct LD.TopicID, R.ID, R.Topic, R.CountLikes, R.CountDisLikes, LD.UserName, LD.Clikes

FROM Rating As R

LEFT JOIN LikeDislike AS LD on LD.TopicID = R.ID
```

The above `SELECT` statement displays results fine but also includes duplicates. I want to remove duplicates when the data is displayed, I tried using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, but with no luck, maybe because I am not using it correctly.

To be more clear and less confusing let me tell you what exactly each table does and what I am trying to achieve.

The `Rating` table has following columns (`ID, Topic, CountLikes, CountDisLikes, Extra, CreatedByUser`). It stores topic information and number of likes and dislikes for each topics and the `UserID` of the user who created that topic.

Rating table with sample data

```
ID  Topic               CountLikes  CountDisLikes  Extra        CreatedByUser
1   Do You Like This       211          58          YesId                2
2   Or This                17           25          This also            3
79  Testing at home        1             0          Testing at home      2
80  Testing at home again  1             0          Testing              2
82  testing dislikes       0             1          Testing              2
76  Testing part 3         7             5          Testing 3            4
77  Testing part 4         16            6          Testing 4            5
```

The `LikeDisLike` table has following columns (`ID, TopicID, UserName, Clikes`). `TopicID` is a FK to the `ID` column in `Rating` table.

LikeDislike table with sample data

```
ID  TopicID UserName    Clikes
213     77      2       TRUE
214     76      2       FALSE
215     77      5       TRUE
194     77      3       TRUE
195     76      3       FALSE
196     2       3       TRUE
197     1       3       FALSE
```

Now what I am trying to do is get information from both of this table without duplicate rows. I need to get data all the columns from `Rating` table + `UserName` and `Clikes` columns from `LikeDislike` table without any duplicate rows

Below are the results with duplicates

```
TopicID ID  Topic            CountLikes   CountDislikes UserName    Clikes
NULL    79  Testing at home    1           0             NULL       NULL
NULL    80  Testing at home2   1           0             NULL       NULL 
NULL    82  testing dislikes   0           1             NULL       NULL
1       1   Do You Like This   211         58            3          FALSE
2       2   Or This            17          25            3          TRUE
76      76  Testing part 3     7           5             2          FALSE
76      76  Testing part 3     7           5             3          FALSE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             2          TRUE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             3          TRUE
77      77  Testing part 4     16          6             5          TRUE
```

Comment: Which rows do you feel are duplicated? Each row contains different values.

Comment: I don't see a single duplicate in your table. If every single value in each column is the same, then that would be a duplicate; that is not the case in your result set.

Comment: A duplicate is a duplicate when all columns of `Rating`  + UserName and Clikes from `LikeDislike` are the same? Why don't you use a `Group By` then? (`SELECT SameColums FROM ... GROUP BY SameColums`)

Comment: UserName appears to differ for each Topic name - you might therefore consider not including this column. That is, for example, for Topic 77 you have 3 different users with like or dislike in so including this will bring back a separate row for each UserName.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you would like the result to show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate data in result from two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391767/remove-duplicate-data-in-result-from-two-tables)

Comment: When you're not getting the answers you want to the questions you pose, the right thing to do is to *edit* your question, add information requested in comments, etc. Don't just re-post your question. I asked previously - I assume you're wanting to eliminate rows which are identical except for the two columns coming from `LikeDislike` - but you haven't told us *how* we're meant to select which values are retained.

Comment: @Damien, In my previous post/question, I was suggested by a another user in comments to create a new question, hence this new post.

Comment: @Aaf - but you haven't *added* any useful information. I.e. you keep talking about duplicate rows, but the rows you're showing are blatantly *not* duplicated. We've offered suggestions (such as that you mean unique in the first 5 columns), but you don't seem to have responded to these hints. If you need help, you need to clearly state what it is that you're after.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the hints. I thought the above SELECT command was resulting into duplicate values, but I missed to see that they were not actually duplicate as I was joining 2 tables. I solved the problem I was facing by correcting the If/Else statements in my web application. Mods, Please close this Question.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in yesterday's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391767/remove-duplicate-data-in-result-from-two-tables), I don't think you understand what DISTINCT is suppose to return you.  Because you have different values in your LikeDislike table, you are returning the DISTINCT rows.

Let's take TopicId 77 for instance.  It returns 3 DISTINCT rows because you have 3 matching records in your LikeDislike table.  If your desired output is a single row where the UserName and Clikes are comma delimted, that is possible -- look into using `for xml` and perhaps `stuff` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14384130/1073631) is a recent answer on the subject).  Or if you want to return the first row that matches the TopicId, then that is possible as well -- look into using a subquery with `row_number`.

Please let us know your desired output and we can help provide a solution.

Good luck.

Comment: You are right, the username for each user in Likedislike table is different. In my web application when a user likes a topic it gets added to the likedislike table wiht a topic Id and UserID, so every time a user likes/dislikes a topic it will create a new entry in the likedislike table, thats why the TopicIDs are repeated but with different userID. May be the SELECT statement I am using is incorrect to fetch data from both the tables. I want all the columns from both the tables in my result set but with topics listed only once.